# Google Chrome, Google Instant not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

When using Google Chrome (6.0.472.63) the "Google Instant" feature is seemingly unavailable; although it was working a week or so ago, I'm unsure when it actually stopped.

The Google Instant feature does work for me in Firefox (3.6.10) and Safari (5.0.2).

Has anyone else had an issue like this or know how to get it working in Chrome?

**Update**

Oddly enough, going to `www.google.ca` has google instant working for me (I am in Canada), does anyone know why it won't work on `www.google.com`?

Comment: Are you using the Omnibar here or the website? If the latter, this will be migrated

Comment: I am using the website

Comment: Did you try a Command/Control+Shift+R?

Comment: Yea I've done Command+Shift+R, no difference

Comment: Try clearing your cache first. And I'm not sure whether signing into a google account makes a difference, but try that too.

Comment: Clearing the cache did it; after I re-logged into my google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As suggested, I've converted my comment into an "answer."*

Try clearing your cache first. And I'm not sure whether signing into a google account makes a difference, but try that too.

Answer (score 0):

Check that JavaScript is enabled in Chrome.  For this you can go to Options > Under the Hood > Content Settings > JavaScript.

If JavaScript happens to be disabled Instant Search won't work.

Comment: JavaScript was already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have not turned off your Google instant in the search settings.

If yes, then turn it off.